# Running Endpoint locally could not provide access to API explorer when HTTP proxy is enabled

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, http-proxy

I'm using Android Studio(0.5.8) on Window7 x64 for developing my Android App with Google AppEngine backend.

If my machine is having direct internet access and I launch backend locally (as DevApp Server) and access my API Endpoints through webbrowser (chrome) it is all working as expected.

Accessing api explorer is also working fine from webbrowser.

```
http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer
```

But if I have configured internet through http proxy (in Android Studio and also in webbrowser) then webbrowser displays initial page of backend but can't access endpoint api explorer.

And deploying appbackend in Google AppEngine also fails with errors.

```
gradlew backend:appengineUpdate
```

Same is working fine if direct internet access is available (not via http proxy).

How can we make it work with http proxy also? Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to tell any command that wraps appcfg (appengineUpdate is one of them) what the http/https proxy is.

In your build.gradle file add to the configuration (more info at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin)

```
appengine {
    httpProxy = "some proxy"
}
```

I'm not sure about the api explorer though.